# How to join tables with hook_views_data

Tags: 7, views

I have two tables activity and activity_map. I need to join both the tables by aid. Below is my code for hook_views_data. Base table is working fine including custom text handler. But I do not see the joined table(activity_map) fields (entity_id, entity_type)  either in fields section nor in arguments or filters. Am I missing anything?

```
  <?php

    /**
 * Implements hook_views_data
 */
function activity_teamie_views_data() {
  $data['activity_teamie']['table']['group'] = t('Activity');
  $data['activity_teamie']['table']['base'] = array(
    'title' => t('Activity'),
    'field' => 'aid',
    'help' => t('Activity feed item')
  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['aid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Activity ID (aid)'),
    'help' => t('Activity ID'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric'
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric'
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort'
    )
  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['template'] = array(
      'real field' => 'template',
      'title' => 'Activity',
      'help' => 'Text describing the activity',
      'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'activity_teamie_handler_field_activity_text',
      ),

  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['data'] = array(
    'title' => 'Data',
    'help' => 'Data array',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
    ),
  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['created'] = array(
    'title' => t('Created'),
    'help' => t('Created timestamp'),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date'
    )
  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['updated'] = array(
    'title' => t('Updated'),
    'help' => t('Updated timestamp'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date'
    )
  );

  /* ACTIVITY MAP */
  $data['activity_teamie_map']['table']['group'] = t('Activity');

  // Join with the {activity} table
  $data['activity_teamie']['table']['join'] = array(
    'activity_teamie_map' => array(
      'left_field' => 'aid',
      'field' => 'aid'
    )
  );
  $data['activity_teamie_map']['aid'] = array(
      'title' => t('Aid Map'),
      'help' => t('Aid Map'),
    'field' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
  ),
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric'
  ),
      'argument' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric'
  )
  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['entity_type'] = array(
    'title' => t('Entity type'),
    'help' => t('Entity type of the associated entity'),
  'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
  ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string'
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string'
    )
  );
  $data['activity_teamie']['entity_id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Entity ID'),
    'help' => t('Entity ID of the associated entity'),
  'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
  ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_numeric'
    )
  );
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Did you try defining the join in the base table?

Comment: Yes. and edited my question with latest code. can you please help

Comment: Since I don't have enough time to try it, the best I can offer is point you to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/how-do-i-display-an-external-database-data/3321#3321 . Those steps allow you to create a views integration for an arbitrary schema, and then you can dump the code and check it against yours to find the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
$data['activity_teamie']['table']['join'] = array(
  'activity_teamie_map' => array(
    'left_field' => 'aid',
    'field' => 'aid'
  )
);
```

You actually want to join the other way round.kk

A general tip, try to think of some kind of similar join relation in Drupal core and look it up in views/modules/$module.views.inc

```
$data['activity_teamie']['entity_id'] = array(
```

Isn't `entity_id` part of `activity_teamie_map`?